# Removing dark burn mark from white shirt

Tags: clothing

I noticed (a bit too late) that a second hand striped white shirt I bought in a charity had a small dark burn mark - see picture. Is there any way to hide it or remove it?

[image]

Comment: What is the location of the burn mark relative to the entire shirt, from what I can see, it is along the button line, but high or low is it?

Comment: About half actually or slightly lower than that.

Comment: You might get lucky and find a way to hide it, but don't count on removing it. Burns can't really be reversed. You can put jam on a burnt slice of toast, but you can't turn the toast back into bread.

Comment: Finding a way to hide it basically what I'm enquiring about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the fibres that are burnt you can do little to remove the burn, anything you do will wear it out if the fibres are already damaged.

A careful hand wash with extra attention to the spot may dislodge any burnt jam or other dirt.

Using a chlorine or peroxide bleach may save the day if it is an organic stain that looks like a burn.  Strong bleaches will weaken fabric and may strip the colour from the nearby details so test out of sight first.

Using a white marker carefully (check in a hidden spot first) may just be able to make your spot the same colour as the shirt but not remove it.

Comment: @drake035 There are white laundry markers for labelling dark clothes.

Comment: @Stan My wife once purchased some white iron on tape that was intended for stamping names with dark ink on dark clothes.  It left a very thin opaque white film, almost like latex or thick paint.  It does obscure the weave but was pretty thin.  A resin based (as opposed to wax) thermal transfer white ribbon may also be an option but do tests first before working in visible areas.